# how to display previously selected select options displayed in select box in php with sql

Tags: php, mysql

```
<tr>
  <td>Select location</td>
  <td>
    <select name="contractors" id="contractors" class="autofill" style="width:100%" onchange="fetch_con1(this.value);">
        <option value="all" selected='selected'>All contractors</option>

        <?php $location->location_options(); ?> 
    </select>   
  </td>
</tr>
```

Above is part of my code .when i select location and if I click submit button after page refreshed, it is not showing previously entered location..and i am display  locations from database by calling `function(<?php $location->location_options(); ?>)`. and this my location fuction:

```
function location_options() {       
    global $db;     
    $query = 'SELECT * from locations ORDER by location_name ASC';      
    $result = $db->query($query) or die($db->error);        
    $options = '';  

    if ($location_id!= '') {            
        while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {              
            if ($location_id == $row['location_id']) {              
                $options .= '<option selected="selected" value="'.$row['location_id'].'">'.$row['location_name'].'</option>';               
            } else  {               
               $options .= '<option value="'.$row['location_id'].'">'.$row['location_name'].'</option>';                
            }           
        }       
    } else {            
       while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {              
           $options .= '<option value="'.$row['location_id'].'">'.$row['location_name'].'</option>';            
       }        
    }       
       echo $options;       
    }
```

AND this is my location function

Comment: Can you provide the contents of your location_options() function? You're going to need to pick up the value of the select from the $_POST data when the form is submitted, and then compare this value to the values you retrieve when your function runs and ensure that the matching location has a 'selected' element in it's HTML markup. A more specific answer with code is going to require the contents of that function though.

Comment: Remove "selected='selected'" from 'all contractors' and make sure that you add 'selected="selected"' in the correct/selected element in $location->location_options()

Comment: where is the initial `$location_id` set? In your function you test for `$location_id!=''` but it doesn't at that point exist so I guess the else part of the statement always equates to true.

Comment: Hi i added location code can you please suggest me line where i sud put selected with syntax

Answer (score 0):

If `$location_id` is defined outwith the function then this might work as expected, though as was pointed out in a previous comment - you ought to also remove the `selected='selected'` from the hardcoded option 'All Contractors'

```
function location_options() {       
    global $db;
    global $location_id;
    /* Assume that the javascript function sends a post / get request with location_id as a parameter */
    if( isset( $_REQUEST['location_id'] ) ) $location_id=$_REQUEST['location_id'];

    $query = 'SELECT * from locations ORDER by location_name ASC';      
    $result = $db->query($query) or die($db->error);        
    $options = '';  

    if( isset( $location_id ) && $location_id!= '' ) {            
        while( $row = $result->fetch_array() ) {   
            $selected=( $location_id == $row['location_id'] ) ? " selected='selected'" : "";
            $options.='<option '.$selected.' value="'.$row['location_id'].'">'.$row['location_name'];
        }
    } else {            
       while( $row = $result->fetch_array() ) {
           $options .= '<option value="'.$row['location_id'].'">'.$row['location_name'];            
       }        
    }       
    echo $options;       
}
```